# error TS2307: Cannot find module 'bluebird'

Tags: node.js, import, typescript, angular

I am currently trying to develop an app using **Ionic 2** and **Angular 2** with **Typescript version**. I decided to use the library **amqp-ts** to include messaging in my app. I installed the library via npm like:

```
npm install amqp-ts
```

Everything went fine and now I've got something like this:

```
/ app root directory
+ node_modules
    - amqp-ts
        - lib 
            -  amqp-ts.d.ts
        - node_modules
            -  amqplib
            -  bluebird
            -  winston
```

The problems begin now: I import the library into my component as it is done in the example of [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqp-ts)...

```
import * as Amqp from "amqp-ts";
```

... and when I try to deploy the app I get the next error messages:

```
TypeScript error: C:/APPs/Test/Ionic2Angular2App/node_modules/amqp-ts/lib/amqp-ts.d.ts(2,26): Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'bluebird'.
TypeScript error: C:/APPs/Test/Ionic2Angular2App/node_modules/amqp-ts/lib/amqp-ts.d.ts(50,12): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
```

**1. The line related to the first error message**

```
// exported Typescript type definition for AmqpSimple
import * as Promise from "bluebird";
[...]
```

**2. The line related to the second error message (same file: amqp-ts.d.ts)**

```
export class Message {
    content: Buffer;
    [...]
}
```

I hope you can help me, please.

Comment: Have you installed the typings for that library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Additionally to regular package install you need to install TypeScript typings. Typings are like header files, they contain all methods/classes/interfaces definitions.

To install typings you need a typings tool. The best way is to install it globally so you can use it in every project

```
npm install typings --global
```

Then installing new typings inside your project is pretty simple, first search for library:

```
typings search bluebird
```

Install it :

```
typings install --save bluebird
```

More info : https://github.com/typings/typings

Comment: thank you so much, it solved the first error message. I still have the second one ("cannot find name Buffer"), any idea?

Comment: same stuff, you need to know which library provides Buffer typings. Buffer is an internal NodeJS thing, so the best way is to install nodejs typings `typings install --save node`

Comment: anyway, I see that this ampq lib stil uses the TSD (https://github.com/abreits/amqp-ts/blob/master/tsd.json), check the Typings/migration from TSD documentation, it should help you solve future problems (probably the next error will be missing `winston` and `when` typings). I'm not sure how to deal with `Typings` because I'm also bound to TSD, but for example try referencing the `node_modules/ampq-ts/libs/typings/tsd.d.ts` file (`<reference path="..." />`)

Answer (score 0):

I too faced same issue, but for me above answer is not working.
While simply running :

```
npm i bluebird
```

resolving the issue